# How to manually open a port in Juju?

Tags: juju

After deploying a service, I would like to manually open a port in that service. Is there a way to do this manually?

I know expose will open a port, but I would like to manually open a different port.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in juju as a round about way. Juju provides a `juju run` command which allows execution of commands against a remote Juju unit.

So, for example, if you have an application deployed called `foo`, with the unit `foo/0` you could do the following:

```
juju run --unit foo/0 "open-port 8000"
```

Replacing `8000` with whichever port you need. There are a plethora of hook-tools you can invoke in addition to standard commands like `whoami`.

For that list you can run `juju help-tool` and for more information on each tool `juju help-tool open-port`.

I'd also make sure you file a bug against the charm if that port is supposed to be open but is not.

Answer (score -3):

It's probably `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport port_number_here -j ACCEPT`.